# Setting environment variable in a ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, environment-variables

I am running ansible-playbook command in a docker container. Ansible is installed in the docker container. I want to set an environment variable that is specific to the container in my playbook task.

I tried:

```yaml
---
- name: Run Ansible playbook
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Execute a command with specific environment variables
      command: your_command
      environment:
        MY_VARIABLE: my_value
```

This does not set the environment MY_VARIABLE at the container level.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behavior.

From the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_environment.html):

> When you set a value with `environment:` at the play or block level, it is available only to tasks within the play or block that are executed by the same user. The `environment:` keyword does not affect Ansible itself, Ansible configuration settings, the environment for other users, or the execution of other plugins like lookups and filters.

So it should not set the variable on the container level. If you need that environment variable for other processes in the same container after Ansible playbook run, the proper solution would be to use `ENV` on your Dockerfile or pass it to `docker run` via `-e` parameter.